# Converting objects into suitable numerical values

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

This is a salary dataset composed of the following columns:

```
['work_year', 'experience_level', 'employment_type',
   'job_title', 'salary', 'salary_currency', 'salary_in_usd',
   'employee_residence', 'remote_ratio', 'company_location',
   'company_size'],
  dtype='object')
```

1. I want to look at the comparison between the features (experience_lvl, employment_type, job_title, salary_currency and remote ratio) and the label (salary).
2. I have to make the feature engineering part, which includes converting experience level, employment type and salary currency to suitable numerical values.
3. How can that be done? What is the optimal solution in this case?

[The three columns that have to be converted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzUCs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You could use e.g. one-hot encoding to transform a dataframe like

| index | experience_level | employment_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | EX | CT |
| 1 | EX | PT |
| 2 | MI | CT |
| 3 | MI | FT |
| 4 | EX | PT |

to a dataframe like

| index | experience_level_EN | experience_level_EX | experience_level_MI | experience_level_SE | employment_type_CT | employment_type_FL | employment_type_FT | employment_type_PT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

as follows:

```
cat_cols = ['experience_level', 'employment_type']
df_encoded = df.drop(columns=cat_cols)
for col in cat_cols:
    encoder = LabelBinarizer().fit(df[col])
    cols = [f'{col}_{c}' for c in encoder.classes_]
    encoded = pd.DataFrame(encoder.transform(df[col]), columns=cols)
    df_encoded = pd.concat([encoded, df_encoded], axis=1)
```

You may also want to apply this to other columns such as company location, employee_residence, etc., which I assume to be categorical too.